# wp_is_mobile and wp_redirect are not working

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am encountering some problems with the wp_redirect and wp_is_mobile functions, on my Wordpress.

I have to pages :

The mobile form page, that is working fine :

```
<?php
  if (!is_mobile())
  {
    wp_redirect( 'MY URL', 301 ); // Redirect to the non-mobile version of the form
    exit;
  }
?>
// My html form
```

The non-mobile form page, that won't redirect :
(For securities reasons, I currently removed the redirection script)

```
<?php
  if (wp_is_mobile())
  {
    wp_redirect( 'MY URL', 301 ); // Redirect to mobile version of the form
    exit;
  }
?>
// My html form
```

BUT... the local (WAMP) version of this page is working.

Also, i tried to make a page without any HTML code, where the redirecting does work in both cases :

```
<?php
 if (is_mobile())
  {
   wp_redirect( 'MY URL', 301 );
   exit;
  }
 else
  {
   wp_redirect( 'MY URL', 301 );
   exit;
  }
?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you using some sort of caching plugin? (like W3 total cache for example)

Comment: There is the WP Super Cache plugin, that is installed but desactivated.

Comment: try this: turn it on, clear the cache, turn it off again, test.

Comment: It doesn't work. On the mobile version, this is the same problem as ever : Only the title of the page (the "current" page, the redirection is not working) is displayed, the page itself remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I had to do is to recreate the wordpress page. It seems to work fine, now. thanks anyway !